# FileSystemObject

Tags: javascript

My script fly with IE8 when I instantiate the file system object:

```
var fso  = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
alert("does not reach this point");
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you getting some errors, warnings, messages asking you to authorize the execution of ActiveX controls?

Comment: I already approved the ActiveX control.
Where can I see the list of approved controls?

Comment: If you are in IE8, press `F12` to bring up the dev tools - inspect the JS errors.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft blocked `ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")` with a kill bit or removed the registry keys required to launch it for newer versions of IE, including IE 8. This was done for security reasons. So unless you modify the registry, it should not launch.

More on this issue, and solutions are available from MSDN at: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/27092b49-7d3e-4d86-9ffb-223a26037c3f

Modifying the registry to mark FileSystemObject Active Control as Safe: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751977(VS.85).aspx

There is also a similar thread here: ["var f = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');" not working with IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258491/var-f-new-activexobjectscripting-filesystemobject-not-working-with-ie8)