# "var f = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');" not working with IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, activex

I am very new in using ActiveX controll through java script,

I write `var f = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');` in my code and Its was working fine on IE6, but recently I upgraded my IE6 to IE8 and what I found now its not working on IE8, returning the error given below:

> Webpage error details
>
> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; MS-RTC LM 8;
>   .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
>   Timestamp: Wed, 31 Aug 2011 14:23:40 UTC
>
> Message: Automation server can't create object
>       Line: 735
>       Char: 9
>       Code: 0
>       URI: http://localhost:8080/
>
> qocweb/script/main/MainLetter.js

I googled this and found there is something missing in the IE ActiveX setting and got resolved this problem,
But now I have a requirement that it should be solved without playing with IE8 setting.

Can anyone have any idea about this, any suggestion would be really appreciable...

Comment: You recently upgraded from IE6? God Bless <country>

Answer (score 1):

You can not use this component with default security settings due to security reasons. Read [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/iewebdevelopment/thread/27092b49-7d3e-4d86-9ffb-223a26037c3f) for more information.